# can apache both redirect and set CORS headers?

Tags: apache

I encountered the following browser console message, using apache to redirect from http to https

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx. Redirect from 'http://xxx' to 'https://xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://current_page' is therefore not allowed access.

Even though https://xxx has correct CORS headers set.

Turns out that apache's "redirect all" directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName servername
   Redirect permanent / https://servername/
</VirtualHost>
```

apparently needs to include a CORS header or the redirect itself will be rejected by web browser.

Is it possible to have apache's "redirect permanent" also include CORS headers?

I tried this, from random googling:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName xxx
   # hope this preserves url's for the auto redir :)
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
   Redirect permanent / https://xxx/
</VirtualHost>
```

Or any other work around here?

Comment: I would have expected this idea to work. What do the actual HTTP response headers show? How are you setting these CORS headers for your actual pages, if you aren't doing this in your Apache config?

Comment: Also note that you will need to make sure that all local caches are cleared before testing. The earlier _permanent_ redirect (that didn't include the CORS headers) will have been cached, so any new requests will not hit your server and see the update until this is cleared.

Comment: @w3dk You were right, it did work, but the browser was caching the non CORS old response.  feel free to convert your comments to an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @w3dk forgot to mention the actual pages are being served off port 443 non apache, a different app with its own headers.  It's a weird config.

Comment: for followers I probably didn't need "all" of those Header directives, FWIW.

Comment: For some visitors, notice that you have to use `always` keyword for adding header. Without it, header is added only to general successful responses (corresponding to 2xx codes), which redirects are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the required HTTP response headers *before* the redirect (which sets the HTTP status and `Location` headers) should work.

However, you will need to make sure that all local caches are cleared before testing. The earlier *permanent* redirect (that didn't include the CORS headers) will have been cached, so any new requests will not hit your server and see the update until the cache is cleared.

The local cache would seem to have been the problem in this instance.